# Android. Adding library com.chiralcode.colorpicker.ColorPicker as dependency

Tags: android, rendering, color-picker

Hi I've got some really stupid problem with using chiralcode.colorpicker

I don't know how to add the library to my dependencies. There is no information [here](https://github.com/chiralcode/Android-Color-Picker) how to add it. I can't use the "Choose Library Dependency" window, because, "chiralcode" is not showing any results, and don't know what to add to build.gradle, because everything causes an error.

On Preview I've got this error:
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- com.chiralcode.colorpicker.ColorPicker (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.

Please help

Comment: Firstly the library is 3 year old, so no one is maintaining it, and it's based on eclipse. So i won't recommend you to use this library, try to find some newer library.

Comment: There are couples, but only this one had a possibility to select couple colors at the same time. That's why I used this one

Comment: Then clone it and rebuild it in studio to make it gradle based or you can simply add that folder in your parent app folder and add in main app gradle file compile project(':lib') while adding also in setting.gradle as include ':app', ':lib'